# How can I run SQL script in OnModelCreating by EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

My program has an existing SQLite database.

In the new version of the program, it needs to add a column for a feature.

Now the program is made by .NET 6 (WPF) and EF Core 6.

I have to detect whether the new column existed and add it or not.

Here is my code in `OnModelCreating` to detect the column existed or not:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    var Result = Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("SELECT Count(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='BindDesign' AND COLUMN_NAME='type'");
}
```

After the code run, it reports this error:

> An attempt was made to use the model while it was being created. A DbContext instance cannot be used inside 'OnModelCreating' in any way that makes use of the model that is being created

How can I solve this? Thank you.

Comment: You should have used the standard migration.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Thanks for answering my question. I have read some articles about migration. However, migration seems to have to input some code in command-line every time but not automatically update while detect the column not exist.

Comment: If your solution requires frequent update of an DB structure, I would rather consider redesigning the DB concept.

Comment: @Michalor No, it will not change frequently, just only for this version.

Comment: Check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70633065/dynamically-add-column-to-existing-table-using-entity-framework
It has links to other similar questions that might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use migrations to add columns in the database.
If you want to apply migrations on startup you can check if the database needs to be migrated and apply the migration with something like this

```
if (_context.Database.GetPendingMigrations().Any()) {
    await _context.Database.MigrateAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to Use Different Context for your schema , the error message is clear , you can on use makes use of the model that is being created.
just make another context for your schema .